# prestashop hook the module in specific position

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a question about how the prestashop hooks work's.

My Buddy asked me to prepare a simple module for him (the module is called "srodkipomocnicze").

The module is prepared (form with an available assortment ...).

Now I can not cope with connecting this module to the "displayHome" hook in proper position.

The problem is that the module is displayed but it is displayed at the very beginning of the page. It is displayed/listed in the correct position in the backend of the page but not on the frontend.

I tried to change its order, i.e. under the slide, before the slide etc., unchanged. the effect can be seen here http://dawid.kapka.net.pl/dawid/

Below the install function and screenshot

```
public function install() { 
      if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) { 
        Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
      }
      if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayHome')) {
        return false;
      }

    $this->installDb();
    return true;
}
public function displayFront(){
    .....
    echo $display;
}

public function hookDisplayHome(){
    return $this->displayFront();
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3s8Y.png)

On the target page, the module will be on one of the subpages and only there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like HTML fail. You may have an extra `<div>` or something like that because page meta and css links are all defined in body and `html` tag is empty. Though it's also possible there's a hidden smarty error somewhere. Enable debug mode to see more.

Comment: It was smarty problem... I have fixed it :-)